# Add a second bridge to a virtual machine

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge

We have a ubuntu-12.04 host running another ubuntu-12.04 virtual machine with kvm virtualization and bridged network interface on eth4. This network allows the virtual machine access to the outside world. I want to add another bridge (br0) to the virtual machine so it can access the local network. But every time I try this, the first bridge "collapses" in some way, as in I cannot access the virtual machine via ssh or even ping it.

The following is the `/etc/network/interfaces` file on the host that I am trying to get to work

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth4
iface eth4 inet manual

auto br4
iface br4 inet static
     address 10.52.4.247
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 10.52.4.1
     dns-nameservers 10.27.3.2 10.25.3.2
     broadcast 10.52.4.255
     bridge_ports eth4
     bridge_stp off
     bridge_maxwait 5
     metric 0

# Local network
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.21
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 5
    metric 0
```

What am I missing here? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why bridges in the virtual machine? I understand why on the physical host, but not in VM. Especially if those are single-port bridges.

Comment: I meant to say that the host is on two separate networks and I want the virtual machine to be part of both those networks.

Comment: Maybe the description is a bit misleading. Provided configuration is from the host, or the guest?

Comment: Its the interfaces file on the host.

Comment: First shot: your VM gets added to a wrong bridge. I presume there were no changes done to the VM yet. Can you confirm by `brctl show` that the VM's interface is really in the correct bridge?